# What can cause SSMA - Empty tables in SQL without error?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

When I migrate from Access 2003 to SQL server 2019, I get half of the tables empty. What can cause this problem and how to fix this? Tables are not empty in Access.

Comment: What is the process that you are using to migrate, the Access Upsizing Wizard? For one of the tables in question, can you right click, Export, choose an ODBC source, and try to export it to your SQL Server? This will be telling. It is likely a data type issue.

Comment: I'm using SSMA migration assistant for Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so at least SOME tables are going to sql server. This is good, as it shows at least  you have "some" of this working.

The tables that don't go? Often this is for two reasons.
the table(s) have bad dates - but SSMAA should spit out a error in that regards.

the other issue is if the table(s) in question have mutli-value fields (attachemnts, or a multi-select type of column. those columns are NOT supported and SQL server has no such data types, so they can't be migrated.

So, you might want to take a look at the offending table, see if any lookup-ups are defined for some of the fields (you can while in design mode - click on the lookup tab - see if a query exists). So, you need to un-convert such tables.

So, in the lookup tab, you see this:

[image]

So, as a general rule, you have to remove those columns. but, they are in fact a "hidden" table and relationship. So, in general you have to create a new child table, and fill out the related data BEFORE you migrate such data.